# sql server parse xml with namespace

Tags: sql-server, xml, xml-namespaces

I'm trying to parse the following xml to get the first tag following the s:Body tag (in this case I'm looking for the string `queryEE`, in other messsages with the same Envelope/Body structure it will be different)

I began playing with it with something like this:

```sql
declare @text varchar(max)

set @text = N'
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Body xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <queryEE xmlns="http://xx.gob.gcaba.xx/">
      <codeEE xmlns="">xxxx</codeEE>
    </queryEE>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>'

declare @x xml

set @x = cast(@text as xml)

select @x.query('/s:Envelope')
```

But I get the error:

```
Msg 2229, Level 16, State 1, Line 16
XQuery [query()]: The name "s" does not denote a namespace.
```

Seems like I'm having troubles with the namespace stuff

When I try with `select @x.query('/Envelope')` I don't get any results at all

---

Thanks to the answers I got from @shnugo I could finally solve it with:

```
select @x.value('local-name((/*:Envelope/*:Body/*)[1])','nvarchar(100)')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it like this:

--your declaration

```
declare @text varchar(max)

set @text = N'
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Body xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <queryEE xmlns="http://xx.gob.gcaba.xx/">
      <codeEE xmlns="">xxxx</codeEE>
    </queryEE>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>'

declare @x xml

set @x = cast(@text as xml);
```

--The query

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES('http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' AS s
                  ,'http://xx.gob.gcaba.xx/' AS innerDflt) 
select @x.value('(/s:Envelope/s:Body/innerDflt:queryEE/codeEE/text())[1]','nvarchar(100)');
```

Some background:

Your XML is a bit weird looking at the namespaces... if the construction is under your control, it would be worth to start here.

There is a namespace `s:` to define `<Envelope>` and `<Body>`. That is fine so far., But then the element `<queryEE>` defines a **default namespace** (no prefix!) and the embedded `<codeEE>` defines another (but empty!) default namespace. I'm pretty sure, that this empty namespaces is created within a query by combining XMLs together...

The **default namespace** tells the engine, that all nodes **without a specific prefix** are living **within** this namespace. So we have to address that.

My code is using `WITH XMLNAMESPACES` to declare all namespaces occuring in the XML. Different to the original XML I define a prefix (`innerDflt`) for the first defualt namespace. That means, we can address `<innerDflt:queryEE>`. The embedded element does not need a namespace. It is living within an empty default (=> no) namespace.

All this said, I just want to point out, that you can use a wildcard too:

```
select @x.value('(/*:Envelope/*:Body/*:queryEE/*:codeEE/text())[1]','nvarchar(100)')
```

And you might even use a deep search

```
select @x.value('(//*:codeEE/text())[1]','nvarchar(100)')
```

But the general advise is: Be as specific as possible.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that' s a great start, but how can I get the node name of the first node after `Body`? in this case it would be `codeEE`, I tried with `select @x.query('(/*:Envelope/*:Body/*[1]/local-name(.))')` but I get a `XQuery [query()]: The XQuery syntax '/function()' is not supported.` error

Comment: @opensas Try `local-name(your/xpath/here)` and use. value() rather than. query()

Comment: thanks a lot for the tip, I could solve it like this: `select T.c.value('local-name(.)', 'nvarchar(100)') FROM @x.nodes('/*:Envelope/*:Body/*[1]') as T(c)` but I could not do somethng like `select @x.value('local-name(/*:Envelope/*:Body/*[1])','nvarchar(100)')`, it gives me `XQuery [value()]: 'local-name()' requires a singleton (or empty sequence), found operand of type 'element(*,xdt:untyped) *'`

Comment: @opensas use `local-name((your/xpath/here)[1])`

Answer (score 1):

Declare your namespace again when using [xquery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/add-namespaces-to-queries-with-with-xmlnamespaces?view=sql-server-2017) for xml with namespaces.

```
declare @text varchar(max)

set @text = N'
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Body xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <queryEE xmlns="http://xx.gob.gcaba.xx/">
      <codeEE xmlns="">xxxx</codeEE>
    </queryEE>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>'

declare @x xml

set @x = cast(@text as xml)

select @x.query('declare default element namespace "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/";   
    /Envelope')
```